# android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException from Android 7.0

Tags: android, crash

The following crash is reported occasionally (rarely), and only from **Android 7.0** devices:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass (WebViewFactory.java:371)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider (WebViewFactory.java:194)
  at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getInstance (WebViewDatabase.java:38)
  at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.isWebViewDatabaseNull (SourceFile:352)
  at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.initializeIfNecessary (SourceFile:260)
  at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.getAdController (SourceFile:303)
  at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.onLayout (SourceFile:478)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1189)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1189)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1982)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1826)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1735)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:321)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:321)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1982)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1826)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1735)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:321)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1982)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1826)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1735)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:321)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:751)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:17838)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5754)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2698)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2371)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1462)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6960)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:907)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:709)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:644)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:893)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:836)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:208)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6267)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1063)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:924)
Caused by: android.webkit.WebViewFactory$MissingWebViewPackageException: 
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewContextAndSetProvider (WebViewFactory.java:270)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass (WebViewFactory.java:330)
```

The stack trace does not contain anything related to the app, so I do not know where to look into this. Could anyone shed some light on this? How to prevent this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is due to that the Webview is updated via google play at the same time as you try to use it in your application.

More info here: 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=506369

Comment: Not a recommendation (since you'll be catching runtime exception): I guess you should be able to catch MissingWebViewPackageException and display a progresspinner, and poll the component you try to use say once a second, when the exception no longer occurs you are safe to use the webview. But this seems to be an ad package from amazon that missbehaves?

Comment: Thanks.  I have disabled Amazon ads because it has caused all kinds of crashes, ANRs.  This is just one of them.

Comment: will it crash just from being declared as a class object above onCreate() or only once were actually using it ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the package `com.google.android.webview` and if it is active.

It's possible that in order to 'debloat' your phone you disabled it, for example via `pm disable com.google.android.webview` (if rooted) or `pm disable-user --user 0 com.google.android.webview` (if not rooted).

It can be re-enabled via Settings > Apps (show system apps) > **Android System WebView** > <kbd>Enable</kbd> or via a terminal (requires `adb` debugging to be [**enabled in settings**](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)):

```sh
pm enable com.google.android.webview
```

If it *is* enabled then try the option `Uninstall Updates` in Settings > Apps — sometimes system upgrades or upgrades via Google Play might install a buggy version of WebView.

Another option is to go to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview and install the update if one is available. If it doesn't fix the error then uninstall it so that your device falls back to its original system webview that came with the stock ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Manually updating Chrome can cause this issue.
Our emulator runs non play version of android so we had to manually update chrome using APK file for another task. Might have been the wrong file. Anything using WebView would crash including its shell app.

Removing Chrome update made WebView work again.